# Using Linq with 2D array, Select not found

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

I want to use Linq to query a 2D array but I get an error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'SimpleGame.ILandscape[*,*]'.
>       'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Code is following:

```
var doors = from landscape in this.map select landscape;
```

I've checked that I included the reference `System.Core` and using `System.Linq`.

Could anyone give some possible causes?

Comment: Also, does this.map implement IEnumerable/IQueryable?

Comment: @Matthew Abbott: Well, it's a 2D array, so I guess some people in Microsoft implemented it.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009019/c-select-unknown-item-from-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C# Multidimensional arrays not implement IEnumerable<T> ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-does-c-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In order to use your multidimensional array with LINQ, you simply need to convert it to `IEnumerable<T>`. It's simple enough, here are two example options for querying

```
int[,] array = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };

var query = from int item in array
            where item % 2 == 0
            select item;

var query2 = from item in array.Cast<int>()
                where item % 2 == 0
                select item;
```

Each syntax will convert the 2D array into an `IEnumerable<T>` (because you say `int item` in one from clause or `array.Cast<int>()` in the other). You can then filter, select, or perform whatever projection you wish using LINQ methods.

Comment: +1 Much more concise than mine (unless you need custom enumeration behavior) ;)

Comment: Thanks. I think I can use foreach in multidimensional array, and does C# also convert it to IEnumerable<T> in order to make foreach work?

Comment: @LLS, `IEnumerable<T>` is not required for the `foreach` looping structure. `Array` implements `IEnumerable`, and this fits the requirement. For the foreach, the structure needs to implement/be implicitly convertible to an enumerable interface (`IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`) or have appropriate `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` methods. See section 8.8.4 of the C# language specification for more details.

Answer (score 22):

Your map is a multidimensional array--these do not support LINQ query operations (see more [Why do C# Multidimensional arrays not implement IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-does-c-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet))

You'll need to either flatten the storage for your array (probably the best way to go for many reasons) or write some custom enumeration code for it:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(T[,] map) {
  for (int row = 0; row < map.GetLength(0); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < map.GetLength(1); col++) {
      yield return map[row,col];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I only saw yield return in GetEnumerator, does it also work to return an IEnumerable<T>?