# Getting a random string from a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The following is my code
I need a random array's individual strings.

```
 string[,] array = new string[4,3]  { { "a1", "b1", "c1" }, {"a2", "b2", "c2" } , 
                                  { "a3", "b3", "c3" }, { "a4", "b4", "c4" } } ;

//string a =???
//string b =???
//string c =???
```

What I need is either a1, b1 c1   OR   a2,b2,c2 etc...

Any ideas will be appreciated..

Thanks, 
Arnab

Comment: @Jayram No, he wants to take an entire row of a 2dim array. It's different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a row of values from a 2D array into a 1D array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797354/how-to-copy-a-row-of-values-from-a-2d-array-into-a-1d-array)

Comment: thanks for pointing..i removed that :)

Comment: Thanks all, Sorry for not detailing the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have understood it, you want to fetch the columns of the row which you get randomly.
For this, just use `Math.Random()` on the row index. In this case array[4].

Comment: Thanks,
Random rnd = new Random();
 int i = rnd.Next(1, 4);
string a= array[i, 0];...

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend on using the [jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array). In the case, you might use this extension method:

```
private static readonly Random _generator = new Random();

public static T RandomItem<T>(this T[] array)
{
    return array[_generator.Next(array.Length)];
}
```

Using it like this:

```
string[][] array = new string[][] {
    new string[] { "a1", "b1", "c1" },
    new string[] { "a2", "b2", "c2" }, 
    new string[] { "a3", "b3", "c3" },
    new string[] { "a4", "b4", "c4" } };

string randomValue = array.RandomItem().RandomItem(); // b2 or c4 or ... etc.
```

All at once:

```
string[] randomValues = array.RandomItem(); // { "a3", "b3", "c3" } or ... etc.
```

or

```
string randomValues = string.Join(", ", array.RandomItem()); // a4, b4, c4
```

[**Why do i recommend** is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>this will group the strings based on the second char of string</strike>

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150678/using-linq-with-2d-array-select-not-found
string[,] array = new string[4,3]  { { "a1", "b1", "c1" }, {"a2", "b2", "c2" } , 
                                  { "a3", "b3", "c3" }, { "a4", "b4", "c4" } } ;

var query = from string item in array
            select item;

var groupby = query.GroupBy(x => x[1]).ToArray();

var rand = new Random();

//Dump is an extension method from LinqPad
groupby[rand.Next(groupby.Length)].Dump();
```

This will output (Randomly):

```
> a1,b1,c1

> a2,b2,c2

> a3,b3,c3

> a4,b4,c4
```

LOL, overkill, Didn't read the array was already "grouped by" the index......

http://www.linqpad.net/